# How to optionally apply environment configuration?

Tags: yaml, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I want to optionally apply a VPC configuration based on whether an environment variable is set.

Something like this:

```
custom:
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - ...
    subnetIds:
      - ...

functions:
  main:
    ...
    vpc: !If
      - ${env:USE_VPC}
      - ${self:custom.vpc}
      - ~
```

I'd also like to do similar for alerts (optionally add emails to receive alerts) and other fields too.

How can this be done?

I've tried the above configuration and a variety of others but just receive various different errors

For example:

```
Configuration error: 
     at 'functions.main.vpc': must have required property 'securityGroupIds'
     at 'functions.main.vpc': must have required property 'subnetIds'
     at 'functions.main.vpc': unrecognized property 'Fn::If'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the best way to achieve such behavior is to use JS/TS-based configuration instead of YAML. With TS/JS, you get full power of a programming language to shape your configuration however you want, including use of such conditional checks to exclude certain parts of the configuration. It's not documented too well, but you can use this as a starting point: https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/v3/legacy/aws-nodejs-typescript

In general, you can do whatever you want, as long as you export a valid object (or a promise that resolves to a valid object) with serverless configuration.